# How to check for existing values in hash and associate values that match?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to achieve the following:

I want to check if an artist already exists in the hash and if so, to associate the entered verse with the specified artist, like this.

```
 hash = [{verse: ['dust in the wind', 'hold on'], artist: kansas, genre: rock}]
```

I tried something like this, but I'm not sure how to associate the new verse entered with existing ones.

```
if all_verses.any? { |hash| hash[:artist].include?(add_verse[:artist])}
   puts "add_verse[:artist] is quite popular! They are already in our catalog!
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def ask(question)
  puts "#{question}"

  answer = gets.chomp
  return answer
end


def add_verse
  hash = {verse: [''], artist: '', genre: ''}

  hash[:verse] = ask('What is the verse?')
  hash[:artist] = ask('Who is the artist?')
  hash[:genre] = ask('What is the genre?')

  return hash
 end

all_verses = []

response = ''
while response != 'no'
  all_verses << add_verse
  response = ask('Do you want to add more?')
  end
end

puts all_verses
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your hash is actually an array:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit, it's adding more verses for the same artist.

```
def ask(question)
    puts "#{question}"
    answer = gets.chomp
    return answer
end

def add_verse
    artist = ask('Who is the artist?')
    verse = ask('What is the verse?')

    @all_verses.each do |item|
        if (item[:artist] == artist)
            item[:verse].push(verse)
            return
        end
    end

    genre = ask('What is the genre?')
    @all_verses << { verse: [verse], artist: artist, genre: genre }
end

@all_verses = []
response = ''

while response != 'no'
    add_verse
    response = ask('Do you want to add more?')
end

puts @all_verses
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this can be refactored in a more elegant and DRY way, but for now here is my working solution to your problem. If an artist already exist, the new verse is added to its array of verses (and without asking again for the genre, since it should be the same), otherwise it creates a new entry.

```
def ask(question)
 puts "#{question}"
 answer = gets.chomp
 return answer
end

@all_verses = []

def add_verse
  hash = {verse: [], artist: '', genre: ''}

  @artist = ask('Who is the artist?')

  if @all_verses.length >0
    if @all_verses.any?{|hash| hash[:artist] == @artist}
      @all_verses.each do |h|
         if h[:artist] == @artist
           h[:verse] << ask('What is the verse?')
         end
      end
    else
        hash[:artist] = @artist
        hash[:verse] << ask('What is the verse?')
        hash[:genre] = ask('What is the genre?')
        @all_verses << hash
    end
  else
    hash[:artist] = @artist
    hash[:verse] << ask('What is the verse?')
    hash[:genre] = ask('What is the genre?')
    @all_verses << hash
  end 
end


response = ''
while response != 'no'
  add_verse
  response = ask('Do you want to add more?')
end

puts @all_verses.inspect
```